# qt can't find namespace qtsnmp

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use qtsnmp library from this github. I compiled the library and generated the .so file under linux.
[qtsnmp](https://github.com/3Hren/QtSnmp)

I'm a newbie with qt, and I just pressed import library -> external library and selected the qtsnmp.so from the folder dialog.

Here is my generated .pro file:

```
    #-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-02-25T11:26:37
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = test
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    wrapper.cpp


HEADERS += \
    wrapper.h

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../lib/ -lqtsnmp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../
```

this is my header file from class wrapper

```
using namespace QtSnmp;
#ifndef WRAPPER_H
#define WRAPPER_H

class wrapper
{
public:
    wrapper();
};

#endif // WRAPPER_H
```

this is the error: /home/vitro/Downloads/QtSnmp-master/test/wrapper.h:1: error: 'QtSnmp' is not a namespace-name
 using namespace QtSnmp;
                 ^
Honestly I don't know what to do, someone would be so kind to help me figure out this issue? I'm supposed to add any extra lines to the .pro file?

these are the files I have in folder from that compiled github:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 vitro users  4096 Feb 25 11:18 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 vitro users  4096 Feb 25 11:59 build-test-Desktop-Debug
drwxr-xr-x 2 vitro users  4096 Feb 25 11:18 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 vitro users  5055 Feb 25 11:24 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x 7 vitro users  4096 Feb 21 15:06 net-snmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 vitro users    68 Feb 21 15:51 QtSnmp.pro
-rw-r--r-- 1 vitro users 18419 Feb 21 16:07 QtSnmp.pro.user
-rw-r--r-- 1 vitro users  1311 Sep 11  2013 README.md
drwx------ 4 vitro users  4096 Feb 25 11:18 src
drwxr-xr-x 2 vitro users  4096 Feb 25 12:02 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 vitro users   327 Feb 25 11:28 test.cpp
```

Comment: You need to `#include` the header file that defines the `QtSnmp` namespace (sorry I don't know what that is). Also putting `using namespace ...` in a header file is very bad practice and can lead to errors in code that includes that header file. If you must use `using namespace Qtsnmp;` then put it in the in cpp file where you need it.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply! I was following the example in the github readme, it looks strange that there is no include folder.

Comment: I don't see that namespace in the library code. Looks to me that the readme is in error.

Comment: same here, I think that readme is only a stub for further implementation. Going to find another library. thanks for your time!!

Comment: I think there is a reasonable example in the test code: https://github.com/3Hren/QtSnmp/tree/master/src/tests/QtSnmpLibTest

Comment: Also since this code is 5+ years old I assume it was designed for Qt4.